# Help with converting recursive formula for sequence into explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on finding a good way to find an explicit formula given the recursive formula of a sequence, which in this case is $$s_{n+1} = 3s_n + 2, s_1 = 1, n \geq 1$$

I'm having trouble finding out what this kind of sequence is called (can it be arithmetic if it's multiplied by an integer?) and in general, what strategies there are to convert things in the form $$a_n = Aa_{n-1} + B$$

so I would appreciate any help on effective ways to deal with this sort of sequence. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

For $$a_n=Aa_{n-1}+B,$$ try to find a $C$ such that the recurrence becomes
$$a_n+C=A(a_{n-1}+C).$$
You need $AC-C=B$ so as long as $A\ne1$ you are in business.
Then
$$a_n+C=A^n(a_0+C)$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, solving this kind of problem comes down to subtracting/adding the right thing.

Let $s_n = b_n - 1$. Then the equation becomes
$$b_{n+1} - 1 = -3 + 3b_n - 2$$
which gives us $b_{n+1} = 3b_n$. So $s_n = A \cdot3^n - 1$ for some $A$, and you use $s_1 = 1$ to work out what $A$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the constant by taking difference and set $t_{n+1} = s_{n+1} - s_n$:
$$
t_{n+1} = 3 t_n = 3^{n-1}t_2 = 3^{n-1} \times (5-1) = 4 \cdot 3^{n-1}
$$
Now sum both expressions on LHS and RHS to get a telescoping sum:
$$
s_{n+1} = 4 \times (3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2} + \ldots 3^{0}) + 1 = \frac{3^{n}-1}{2} +1
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by repeated substitution into the recurrence.

For $a_n=Aa_{n-1}+B$ ($n\ge 1$), we have

$$\begin{align*}
a_1 &=  Aa_0 + B,\\
a_2 &= Aa_1+ B = A^2 a_0 + AB + B \tag{since $a_1 = Aa_0+B$} \\
a_3 &= Aa_2+B = A^3a_0 + A^2 B + AB + B \tag{since $a_2=A^2 a_0 + AB + B $},\\
\end{align*}$$
and from this we can see the general pattern is

$$a_n = A^n a_0 + \left(A^{n-1} + A^{n-2} + \cdots+ A+1\right)B,\quad n\ge 1.$$

(We can prove this by induction quite easily.)

Note that you can simplify this answer using the geometric series formula:

$$A^{n-1} + A^{n-2} + \cdots+ A+1 = \begin{cases}
\frac{A^n-1}{A-1} &\text{if }A\ne 1\\ 
n &\text{if } A=1
\end{cases}.$$